# Deploying to Heroku gave 503 service unavailable - works locally

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, mern, http-status-code-503

locally my project works, but once I deployed I received a 503. I'm assuming something is wrong with my server.js file, but I've only been doing this for 3 months so I'm pretty lost in all honesty on what these error codes me. I reached out to some resources, but to no avail. I know this isn't the most thorough post or question, but I'm really new to this and struggling hard. Thank you for your time.

```js
/* === Dependencies === */
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
/* === Set the PORT to work with deployment environment === */
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
/* === Call Express as app === */
const app = express();


/* === Middleware === */
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(flash());


/* Serve up static assets (usually on heroku) */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(passport.session()); app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));

};

/* === Routing === */

app.use(routes);

/* === Express 404 error handler === */
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('404 in Server.js, route Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

/* === Error Handling === */

/* Development error handler will print stacktrace */
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

/* Production error handler no stacktraces leaked to user */
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

// Connect to Mongo DB
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/mern_authenticate_me",
  {
       useNewUrlParser: true,
       useUnifiedTopology: true,
       useCreateIndex: true,
       useFindAndModify: false
  }
);

/* === Server-Side Authentication w/passport.js on our Model === */
const Account = require('./models/account');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

/* === Mongoose Connection === */
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/mern_authenticate_me', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

/* === Telling Express to Listen === */
app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(` ==> API server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

[Github Repo](https://github.com/eschiavoni2/Project3)

[Deployed](https://fathomless-retreat-04121.herokuapp.com/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLRH8.png)

Comment: Check your app logs and try to find out what's wrong. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging Maybe your app can't connect to your DB

Comment: agreed, 503 mean the app cannot start... something must be broken. Log is the way to go.